# Starting a simple JUnit / Maven project in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I'm trying to find the quickest way to get a simple JUnit test up and running with IntelliJ IDEA and Maven.  This is what I do:

```
File > New Project
Maven > Create from Archetype > org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart
Give it a unique GroupId and ArtifactId ("testingmaven")
Give it a project name ("testingmaven")
Click Finish
```

At this point, I get the following file structure:

```
project
|_src
  |_main
    |_java
      |_testingmaven
        |_App.java
  |_test
    |_java
      |_testingmaven
        |_AppTest.java
```

But I can't run anything.  When I put a simple JUnit test in AppTest.java and click "Build > Run" it forces me to update configurations.  It doesn't seem to recognise my files as Java.

I just want to be able to start a Maven project, write a simple JUnit test, and run the test.

I'm coming from Ruby, so I know I'm just not used to package organisation and IDE configuration.

Am I missing something?
Is it because of the archetype I'm starting with?
When I tried to start a Maven project without an archetype, I didn't get `pom.xml`.
***Is there a better archetype for my purposes?***

Comment: I hope this url will help :https://dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-w-junit-using-maven-and-intellij-pt1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fasters way for creation Maven project is generating it from a console -> import to IDE.

for this purpose you can use `maven-archetype-quickstart` archetype.

Just execute following command:

> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={com.mycompany.app} -DartifactId={my-app-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

You have to replace `{...}` params with your data, like project name and packages.

`maven-archetype-quickstart` automatically adds `junit` to pom file and creates test stub. By default, junit version is **3**. My suggestion is to update it to **4**.

After this you can easily import this project with Intellij Idea:

> File > New > Project from Existing Sources > select pom.xml (double click) > Next ... > Finish

Also don't forget about formatting shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

**Useful link:**

[How to create a Java project with Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

Steps if you've already created your maven project with IntelliJ without archetype:

1. Place cursor somewhere inside your class
2. Press `<Alt>+<Insert>`
3. Select `Test...`
4. Choose the methods you want tested and any other options

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tdd-with-intellij-idea.html)

Notes: in my case, I chose JUnit5. I had to import those modules into the project afterwards (the contextual help offered by pressing `<Alt>+<Enter>` did the trick).